# How to get IEnumerable filled with ErrorMessages from ModelState in ASP.NET Core with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, modelstate

I have the following C# extension:

```
public static class ModelStateHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable Errors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                return modelState.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key,
                kvp => kvp.Value.Errors
                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray())
                .Where(m => m.Value.Any());

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This extension is called from controller to generate a JSON and the following JSON is generated:

```
{
    "error": [
        {
            "key": "Password",
            "value": [
                "The Password field is required."
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Username",
            "value": [
                "The Username field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How this extension method can be modified to return just a list of error messages? Like this:

```
{
    "error": [
        "The Password field is required.",
        "The Username field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am using ModelState.IsValid and returning a BadRequest(new { error = ModelState.Errors() } ); in the ASP.Net Core controller

Comment: `return new { error = modelState.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray() };` _If that doesn't work, try `SelectMany` instead of `Select`._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please do not name your extension class "FooHelper" since Helper is meanless. Since this is your `ModelStateExtenstions` lets call it that way. Also you want to get `IEnumerable<string>` so return it that way.

Here is following code:

```
 public static class ModelStateExtenstions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetErrorMessages(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            return modelState.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
                          .Select(e => String.Join(" ", e.Value.Errors.Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)));
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Since one property can have multiple error messages i decided to join them with empty space. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

And by using SelectMany :

```
var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(x=>x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
```

Extension:

```
public static class ModelStateHelper
{
    public static List<string> Errors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
          return ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(x=>x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
        }
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using List<string> forces you to use specific IEnumerable implementation

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps code like this works:

```
public static class ModelStateHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable Errors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            return modelState.Errors();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```